# Does the sequence defined by $(px)\bmod q$ have a name

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

I am looking for the name of the sequence where the $x$:th element $a_x$ is defined by the function:

$(px)\bmod q$

where $p,q,x\in \Bbb N$ and $ 0\leq x < q$

E.g. $p=2$ and $q=5$ gives the sequence $(0, 2, 4, 1, 3)$

I have come up with some formulas and theorems concerning this sequence. Now I would like to find out if my findings are new or if someone else already has figured this out. If this sequence has a name it would be helpful to know it.

Comment: The multiples of $p$ (modulo $q)\  $ (prototypical example of an *ideal*). $\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque: I do not think that this is what I am after. According to wikipedia an ideal is a concept of ring theory and it is a set. I am talking about a sequence.

Comment: In mathematics, a sequence is an enumerated collection of objects in which repetitions are allowed and order matters. Like a set, it contains members (also called elements, or terms). The number of elements (possibly infinite) is called the length of the sequence. So it's an ordered multiset.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee: Thanks for that clarification of my question. I am looking for the name of a sequence, according to the definition you posted, whose element with index x $a_x = (px) mod\;q$

Comment: @DanielRosin It is the *sequence*  of all multiples of $p$ (modulo $q$). Viewed as a *set* it is a prototypical example of an ideal.

Comment: Polmod in Pari/gp

Comment: That sequence does not have a standard name. The comments suggest some you might use. If you [edit] the question to tell us why you need a name we may be able to help.

Comment: @EthanBolker: thanks for that feedback. I have updated my question to clarify what my goal actually is.

Comment: That sequence appears often in elementary number theory so it's unlikely your results are new. You could browse the first chapters of such texts (probably available on line) to look.

Comment: After looking into elementary number theory books I think the best description of this sequence would be: an arithmetic sequence reduced modulo for a specific modulus